# flash - checkbox, eventchange

Tags: flash

I need help please :). I'm doing an dynamic map of the world between 800BC and 2014 AD, but i'm a stuck.
I have created a text field where the user can enter a date ("date_input") and a checkbox where he/she can choose BC or AD ("BC_check")

For example, if he/she want 520BC, he/she just has to write 520 in date_input and check BC_chack. It will make the movieclip corresponding to the chosen scale (world/continent/region) and era (BC/AD) to the frame 520 ("world_map_neg"). Had the user chosen the year 422AD, it would have taken the movie clip "world_map_pos" to frame 422.

My problem is that the code works the first time, but when i try to deselect BC_check, the map doesn't change, and i have to change the scale for it to change.

Here is the part of the code:

```
/* Aller à date */
date_input.restrict = "0-9";
var date_dynamic: int;
date_input.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, fl_date);
function fl_date(e: Event): void {
date_dynamic = parseInt(date_input.text);
if (BC_check.selected == true)
{
    world_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    america_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    europe_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    asia_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    africa_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    oceania_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    regionx_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
}
else
{
    world_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    america_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    europe_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    asia_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    africa_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    oceania_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
    regionx_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic);
}
}
```

I'm a beginner so I would really appreciate your help. If you need, here is a link to my .fla, but I began only yesterday so it is mostly placeholders: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz9l4d8qb42fsif/ATLAS%201.1.fla

Also, English is not my first language, so don't judge my grammar to harshly :)

Have a good day,
Jeryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to go around my problem:

```
/* Aller à date */
date_input.restrict = "0-9\\-";
var date_dynamic: int;
date_input.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, fl_date);
function fl_date(e: Event): void {
date_dynamic = parseInt(date_input.text);
world_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic - date_dynamic * 2);
world_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic)
regionx_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic - date_dynamic * 2);
regionx_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic)
regiony_map_neg.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic - date_dynamic * 2);
regiony_map_pos.gotoAndStop(date_dynamic)

/*Date World*/
if (date_dynamic < -1 && world_map_neg.visible == true) {} else if (date_dynamic < -1 && world_map_pos.visible == true) {
    world_map_pos.visible = false;
    world_map_neg.visible = true;
} else if (date_dynamic > 1 && world_map_neg.visible == true) {
    world_map_pos.visible = true;
    world_map_neg.visible = false;
} else if (date_dynamic > 1 && world_map_pos.visible == true) {

    /* Date Region X */
} else if (date_dynamic < -1 && regionx_map_neg.visible == true) {} else if (date_dynamic < -1 && regionx_map_pos.visible == true) {
    regionx_map_pos.visible = false;
    regionx_map_neg.visible = true;
} else if (date_dynamic > 1 && regionx_map_neg.visible == true) {
    regionx_map_pos.visible = true;
    regionx_map_neg.visible = false;
} else if (date_dynamic > 1 && regionx_map_pos.visible == true) {

    /* Date Region Y */
} else if (date_dynamic < -1 && regiony_map_neg.visible == true) {} else if (date_dynamic < -1 && regiony_map_pos.visible == true) {
    regiony_map_pos.visible = false;
    regiony_map_neg.visible = true;
} else if (date_dynamic > 1 && regiony_map_neg.visible == true) {
    regiony_map_pos.visible = true;
    regiony_map_neg.visible = false;
} else if (date_dynamic > 1 && regiony_map_pos.visible == true) {}
}
```

It's probably not the best way, but it works :)
When the user enter 586, the program shows the frame 586 of world_map_pos or regionx_map_pos (depending on the region_inpu text field). When the user enters -586, the program sends him or her to the fram 586 of world_map_neg or regionx_map_neg. AD and BC are on two different MovieClips, and I don't need a check box at all :)

Comment: I'll post an update to the file in a few days when I replace most of the placeholders with real maps and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Do this: if I enter '800’ and I check 'BC' then send me to frame 800. But if I DON'T check 'BC' send me to frame 800+800 (that is, **date_dynamic+800**). If I want to go to ANY year AD just send me to year+800.  This should work because, for instance, your year 2014 info. would be on the 2814th frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found a way around it yesterday. Not sure it is the best, but here's what I did:

Comment: Where is what you did?